# What is the scope of Peter’s statement in Acts 10:35?

Tags: acts

In Acts 10:35 Peter says that

> “in every nation the man who fears [God] and does what is right is welcome to Him.”

What is the scope of his statement here, specifically as it pertains to the word, “welcome”? In what way does God “welcome” these people - does it mean that He will find a way to reveal Himself and the way of Jesus Christ, as He did for Cornelius?

Comment: The story shows how the Holy Spirit works in both Cornelius and Peter to prepare the way for the former’s conversion. If I understand your question correctly, then my answer is  “yes,” this story does illustrate how God brings people to Christ and to a knowledge of God. It is the work of the Holy Spirit but also depends on disciples like Peter to serve as witnesses for Christ (cf Mt 9:37, Mt 38:19, Jn 4:38, Rom 10:14-15).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the verse could be translated a bit differently than is quoted in the question.  Consider, first, the grammar, as shown in the interlinear.

[image]

Notice that the word translated as "welcome" is an adjective, and not a verb.  Next, notice that in the interlinear gloss it uses the word "acceptable" for the Greek "dektos."  This is more passive than the idea of "welcome" connotes, although, as God loves everyone, I don't see anything untrue about the concept of His welcoming those of other nations, merely that it is not a good idea to change an inspired word for one of one's own choosing.

This Greek word is used in only four other verses in the Bible.

| Reference | Text (KJV) |
| --- | --- |
| Luk 4:19 | To preach the **acceptable <sup>G1184</sup>** year of the Lord. |
| Luk 4:24 | And he said, Verily I say unto you, No prophet is **accepted <sup>G1184</sup>** in his own country. |
| 2Cor 6:2 | (For he saith, I have heard thee in a time **accepted <sup>G1184</sup>**, and in the day of salvation have I succoured thee: behold, now is the accepted <sup>G2144</sup> time; behold, now is the day of salvation.) |
| Php 4:18 | But I have all, and abound: I am full, having received of Epaphroditus the things which were sent from you, an odour of a sweet smell, a sacrifice **acceptable <sup>G1184</sup>**, wellpleasing to God. |

As the translation shows, it is consistently seen to be "accepted" or "acceptable."  In more than one instance, the idea of "welcome" would not even be a grammatical or theological fit.

But more to the scope of the word itself.

The verse addresses the righteous, God-fearing one who is acceptable with God. This righteous one is depicted as "working righteousness."  The works of righteousness are what demonstrate the person's faith.  Anyone who, in faith, obeys God's commandments and serves Him faithfully, is accepted.

It is the fragrance of the merit of Christ that makes our good works acceptable to God, and it is grace that enables us to do the works for which He rewards us. Our works in and of themselves have no merit. When we have done all that it is possible for us to do, we are to count ourselves as unprofitable servants. We deserve no thanks from God. We have only done what it was our duty to do, and our works could not have been performed in the strength of our own sinful natures.

**Conclusion**

According to this text, anyone, in any "ethnei" (nation), who reveres (phoboumenos) God, and whose righteous works demonstrate this, is to be accepted by God.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

What is the scope of his statement here, specifically as it pertains to the word, “welcome”?

> God It's not partial, but in every nation he who is fearing him and acting righteously is acceptable.  Acts 10:35

Cornelius and his friends were acceptable to God because they feared him and acted righteously, and this was even before Simon was sent to them.

They were like the godly Israelite before Christ came but they did lack the pardon and gifts which came with the proclamation of the kingdom.  They received this blessing through the chief apostle Peter.  Their blessing is connected with and depends on the blessing of Israel in the kingdom.

(Our blessing depends on the opposite.)It actually follows Israel's apostasy.

Cornelius is blessed in accord with a prophetic prediction concerning the nations in the kingdom, As it will be during the millennial eon.  Cornelius was like a representative or candidate for the kingdom, but must hear the word of life in order to be saved.

> Send to Joppa for Simon who is called Peter He will convey to you a message by which you and all your household will be saved.’  Acts 11:14

Peter preaches the same message that he dispatched to the sons of Israel, preaching the evangel a peace through Jesus Christ. (He is Lord of all),
Acts 10:34-43 Is the gospel he preached to Cornelius and his family and friends.

Peter was charged to proclaim to the people and to certify that this one is he who is specified by God to be judge of the living and the dead.  Everyone who is believing in him is to be obtaining the pardon of sins through his name.

So the scope of what Peter preached to Cornelius is representative not only of some of those who heard back in the day when the kingdom was trying to be established, but is now in abeyance.

The kingdom will come on earth and the nations then will be accepted like Cornelius did If they fear him and act righteously.  They will be submitting to Israel's rule.

Comment: Is there, then, "our blessing" and the "blessing of Israel in the Kingdom"... 2 blessings with "ours" being the opposite of "theirs"?

Comment: Hi Mike.  
Our blessings are inherent in the heavens.
who did bless us in every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places in Christ, 4according as He did choose us in him before the foundation of the world, Eph. 1:3
1in whom also we obtained an inheritance, Eph. 1:11

Comment: And Israel's blessings are earthly?

Comment: Israel's blessing will take place on the earth where they will reign as a royal priesthood,a holy nation unto Jehovah for making the knowledge of His glory cover the earth as the waters cover the sea, and bless all the families and nations of the earth.

Comment: What then is the point of the church provoking Israel unto jealousy (Romans 11) if they are on their own track to blessing?

Comment: Israel is Gods appointed channel of blessing to the nations.  The book of acts is full of the jealousy of the Jews whenever they see the nations receiving God's  gifts.  Perhaps some of them looked at Jesus again in a more favorable light.  In doing so they may have come to believe in Him as their Messiah and some of them in the process were saved.

Comment: Israel is the channel of blessing to the nations, yes.  That blessing is Jesus, yes. Israel's house (the nation) is desolate and they shall see him no more until they say, "Blessed is He...".   They are not all Israel who are of Israel...God is no respecter of persons.  If they get saved they are in the Church.  We, says Peter, are a royal priesthood, an holy nation.  We are grafted in to what they were cut out of...one olive tree.  They can be grafted in again but they cannot approach via some alternate track and they dare not hope in their lineage.

Comment: The Israel of God refers to Jewish believers in Jesus Christ, to those who are spiritual as well as physical descendants of Abraham. They are the Jews who accepted the Lord Jesus as their Messiah, the remnant chosen ones by grace mentioned in Ro.11:5 
Look at who Peter is addressing when he refers to them as a holy nation.  Peter, an apostle of Jesus Christ, To the elect who are exiles of the Dispersion throughout ..1 Peter 1. Look at Exodus 19:6 I ask then, did they stumble so as to fall beyond recovery?f Certainly not!  Course God well graft them back. Let's move this to chat if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132071/discussion-between-mike-borden-and-sherrie).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the following discussion we will define “Pagan” as a person who is neither Christian nor Jew.  Then we ask the question, “Can pagans be saved, as pagans?”  The Bible appears to answer affirmatively.

> “For when Gentiles, who do not have the law, by nature do what the law
> requires, they are a law to themselves, even though they do not have
> the law.  They show that the work of the law is written on their
> hearts, while their conscience also bears witness, and their
> conflicting thoughts accuse or even excuse them.”  Rom 2:14, 15.

This is similar to the idea Paul expresses in the previous chapter of Rom 1:

> **18** The wrath of **God is being revealed from heaven** against all the godlessness and wickedness of men who suppress the truth by their
> wickedness. **19** For what may be known about God is plain to them,
> because God has made it plain to them. **20** For since the creation
> of the world God’s invisible qualities, His eternal power and divine
> nature, **have been clearly seen**, being understood from His workmanship,
> so that men are without excuse. **21**For **although they knew God**, they
> neither glorified Him as God nor gave thanks to Him, but they became
> futile in their thinking and darkened in their foolish hearts.

See also Ps 87:4-6.  Further, 1 John 4:7 claims that, “Everyone who loves has been born of God and knows God.”  More explicitly, John 1:9 and Rom 1:18-20 also suggest that all people receive some revelation of God and all are without excuse.  See also Prov 4:18 and Luke 12:47, 48.

This is consistent with the non-exclusive attitude of God to membership of Israel Israel (see appendix below).  In fact, the Bible contains numerous examples of pagans behaving like (or often better than) Jews and Christians and receiving divine information, visions and advising Jews and Christians.

- Pharaoh rebukes Abram after a vision from God.  Gen 12:17-20
- Abimelech rebukes Abraham after a vision from God.  Gen 20:3-6
- Abimelech rebukes Isaac about Rebekah.  Gen 26:8-11
- The Philistine king Achish appeared to recognize YHWH, the LORD, in 1 Sam 29:6, 7.
- King Necho of Egypt rebukes Josiah’s foolishness.  2 Chron 35:20-22
- Jonah was the divine agent in saving the pagan city of Nineveh without the need for them becoming Jews.  Jonah 3:4-10
- The magi (“wise men”) of the east were avid students of Scripture.  Matt 2:1, 2, 11, 12.
- Several Roman Centurions were obviously saved.  Matt 8:5-12, Luke 23:47, Acts 10:30-35.

Peter aptly summarized this situation when he is recorded as saying:

> Acts 10:34, 35 - Then Peter began to speak: “I now truly understand
> that God does not show favoritism, but welcomes those from every
> nation who fear Him and do what is right.

**APPENDIX - Non-exclusive Israel**

Note that while Israel was chosen as the instrument to tell and show the world of God’s saving grace, salvation was always available to all people.  Indeed, the Old Testament contains many examples of foreigners becoming part of Israel, indicating that the Israelite Covenant was open to all and was never exclusive.  For example:

- Abraham’s own household must have consisted of perhaps 2000 people just to be able to raise an army of 318 men to liberate Lot, Gen 14:14.  Indeed, Abraham’s chief servant (from Damascus) was clearly a believer and very devout as shown in Gen 24.
- The unfortunate story in Gen 38 about Judah and Tamar shows that a foreigner became the mother of the tribe of Judah.
- When Jacob entered Egypt, his family numbered 75 people (Acts 7:14, Ex 1:5).  Some of these were not direct descendants of Abraham such as the wives of the 12 patriarchs, notably Joseph’s own wife.  215 years and four generations later at the exodus, Israel’s army had over 600,000 men, excluding women and children, (Ex 12:37, Num 1:46, etc) suggesting a total population of several million people, requiring many additions.  This included a significant mixed multitude (Ex 12:38) showing that Israel obviously consisted of many non-biological Jews had joined.  (Note that it is biologically impossible for Israelite numbers to have grown from 75 to several million biologically without many outside additions.)
- Moses married a Midianite (Ex 2:16-21) also known as a Cushite.  Miriam and Aaron were severely reprimanded and punished for displaying racism (Num 12:1, 2)
- Caleb, who represented and led the tribe of Judah was a Kennizite (Num 32:12).
- Rahab was a Canaanite (Josh 2:1, 2, Matt 1:5)
- Ruth was Moabite (Ruth 1:4 16, 17, Matt 1:5) – these last two make King David descended from foreigners (Ruth 4:13-16).
- Uriah was a Hittite (2 Sam 11:3)
- King David’s elite personal regiment consisted of Gittites, that is, Philistines (2 Sam 15:18-22, 1 Chron 18:17)
- Isa 56:6, 7 - And the foreigners who join themselves to the LORD to minister to Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My covenant—I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful in My house of prayer.  Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for My house will be called a house of prayer for all the nations.”  See also V3.
- The Rechabites were Kenites (Jer 35:1-19)
- Many other foreigners lived in Israel (1 Chron 22:2, 17, 2 Chron 30:25)
- In Esther’s time “many of the people of the land became Jews” (Esther 8:17, 9:27)
- Even in NT times, many Jewish synagogues were attended by godly gentiles converted to Judaism (Acts 13:16, 26, 16:14, 17:17)
- Many Jewish proselytes came to worship in Jerusalem (John 20:20, Acts 2:9-11)
- Jesus quotes Isa 56:7, “My house shall be a house of prayer for all nations”, Mark 11:17.
- Further, biological Israelites could opt out of the covenant and be cut-off (Ex 30:33, 38, 31:14, Lev 7:20, 21, 25, 27).

Thus, it is abundantly clear that membership of Israel was always open to all and voluntary.

Comment: Hi Dottard, can you explain what you mean by "Can pagans be saved as pagans?" Are you saying that they can remain as pagans and be saved?

Comment: @MartinHemsley - It goes without saying that there is only one means to be saved and that is by the merits of Jesus Christ alone (Acts 4:12 etc).  However, not everyone has the privilege of knowing Christ in this life - many die without ever having heard the Name of Jesus - the material above addresses this question.  Such saved "pagans" will meet Christ in the next life and discover much more - as we all will.  None of has the full picture any anyway!

Comment: Exactly! We have to be careful how we describe the picture that we do not see very clearly. I'm sure we'll be in for a lot of surprises. But just because God uses a pagan doesn't necessarily mean that pagan is saved. Many of those you describe left paganism to follow the One True God. To fear him is to forsake all other gods. Membership is open to all, but we have to sign up and meet the requirements. I didn't feel that was clear in your first paragraph.

Comment: @MartinHemsley - fair point.  Jonah's experience is salutary.  In any case, my examples from Rom 1:18-21 and 2:14, 15 are more instructive.

Comment: Do you not think that anyone, of any nation, who fears (the true) God and works (actual) righteousness will be reached by God somehow with a further revelation of Christ in this life, as is exemplified in this very passage as well as Acts 16:9-10?

Comment: @MikeBorden - probably yes in some way (I am aware of a few examples of this).  I am also aware that John 1:9 also says: "The true Light who gives light to **every man** was coming into the world."

Comment: Yes, everyone has light and is without excuse.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the scope of Peter’s statement in Acts 10:35?**

**God is not partial.**

Jews did not enter the houses of Gentiles, Peter however  affected  by the vision entered the house of  Cornelius and after   he related  what happened, Peter  was moved   and declared:

In Acts 10:35

> “in every nation, the man who fears [God] and does what is right is
> welcome to Him.”

Peter said these words because he had just seen how God’s own hand directed matters so that a family of Gentiles, formerly considered unclean and unacceptable, became acceptable to Him.

God is not partial, He places no significance on color, ethnicity, language, or national group, anyone who fears God and does what is right is acceptable to him.

Galatians 3:26-28 NASB

> 26 For you are all sons and daughters of God through faith in Christ
> Jesus. 27 For all of you who were baptized into Christ have clothed
> yourselves with Christ. 28 **There is neither Jew nor Greek,** there is
> neither slave nor free, there is [a]neither male nor female; for you
> are all one in Christ Jesus.

Revelation 7:9-10 NASB

A Multitude from the Tribulation

> 9 After these things I looked, and behold, a great multitude which no
> one could count, **from every nation and all the tribes, peoples, and
> languages,** standing before the throne and before the Lamb, clothed in
> white robes, and palm branches were in their hands; 10 and they *cried
> out with a loud voice, saying, “Salvation belongs to our God who sits
> on the throne, and to the Lamb.”